# Upgrade from 2008 RTM to 2008 R2 RTM failed due to perf-ReportServer-rsctr.dll is being used by another process

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade

I was upgrading SQL Server 2008  RTM on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 to SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM. I got this error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\perf-ReportServer-rsctr.dll' because it is being
>   used by another process.
>
> Service 'MSSQLServer' Stop request timed
>   out and this occurred during
>   'sqlEngineConfigAction_upgrade_shutdowninstance_cpu64 ' phase and I
>   stopped & disabled WMI even though it was not running and did not
>   install process monitor to see who locked this dll. I also shutdown
>   application servers before starting the upgrade to avoid them to
>   attempt to connect to SQL Server.

After the failed upgrade  full-text search, SQL Server Replication, Database Engine Services, Analysis Services and Reporting Services status were Failed but others succeeded such as management studio & integration Services etc and then I restarted the server as it was required  but as expected after reboot server was still in 2008 RTM and when I queried `select @@version`.

Do you think I should upgrade SQL 2008 to latest service pack SP4 and upgrade as this bug may have been fixed on latest service packs and then upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 or just figure out which process or application that may be using this dll?

Comment: Apply SP4, **shut down Reporting Services** and all other non-essential services, then try the upgrade again. Make sure you slipstream R2 SP3 and don't start with applying an upgrade to RTM.

Comment: Thanks Aaron but the Customers requested only SQL 2008 R2 RTM so this is not a option for me. Reporting service would be upgraded so stopping this service will not affect upgrade SSRS along with DB engine? what are some of the non-essential services that you recommend?

Comment: Why do they want a version that is out of support? RTM is an absolutely terrible idea and IMHO you have a moral obligation to try and talk them out of it. Yes, you can upgrade services that are not running. I can't give you an inventory of non-essential services because I don't know what services you're running.